# Java - Check whether a number given by the user from console is in a text file

Tags: java

I'm kinda new to Java so I'm looking for an help to do this.

As the title says, I'm trying to write a program that checks if a number given by the user from console is inside a text file with one number for each line or not.

I am using the `Scanner` class to check every line, but I am having problems with what condition the if statement should have when the number is found inside the file.
I wrote down this part code (I'm not even sure if it's correct itself, so correct me if I'm wrong):

```
int lines = 0;
while (filescanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = filescanner.nextLine();
    lines++;
    if(conditon here) {
        System.out.println("I found the number on line " + lines);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `line.contains(value)` You might need to call the `toString()` method on the value

Comment: What is the type of `filesscanner` variable?

Comment: Where is the part where you let the user input the number ? How do you get the input ?

Comment: @curlyBraces filescanner is a Scanner variable with argument the file variable previously declared(File file=new File(<path of my text file>)

Comment: @Exception_al i let the user input the number with: int number;  number=keyboard.nextInt();   the keyboard variable is another Scanner type(Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the input number from `Scanner keyboard`, you can get its value like this:

```
String input = keyboard.next();
```

Then your if condition can be `if(line.contains(input))`

Comment: this really noice :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the line to an integer and then test it. If it is not an integer the parseInt method throws an exception.

```
try {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(line);
    if (n == number) {
        // found it
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Not a number
}
```